# Remove AD PS Module after installing gMSA on Windows Server 2012 R2

Tags: active-directory, windows-server-2012-r2, powershell, managed-service-accounts

I installed a Group Managed Service Account on a Windows 2012 R2 Server.  In doing so, I had to install the Active Directory module for Windows PowerShell Feature.  Is it possible to uninstall that Feature now that the gMSA has been installed?  Or will it break the gMSA (i.e. the ability to autorotate the password)?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the server will still be able to use the gMSA if the AD module is uninstalled.

I'm not sure why you would bother though. The module is only about 5 MB worth of drive space comprised of mostly XML and it doesn't have any executables or services that run in the background. Why not keep a useful management tool installed?

Comment: OK.  Thanks!  We generally prefer to remove Roles and Features that are not (or no longer) needed on a server.  But I'll discuss it with the rest of the team and see what the other opinions are.  Thanks again!